# Finding $U$ s.t $\mu(U-E) \lt \epsilon$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,B,\mu)$ be a measure space where $\mu(X) =1 $ , $X$ is a metric space and $B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

Let $E \subset X$ be closed, I want to prove that given $ \epsilon$ there is $U $ open , $E \subset U$ s.t $\mu(U - E ) \lt \epsilon$.

My attempt :

Define $W = \{ U : E \subset U$ is open $\}$. then $X \in W$ so $W \neq \emptyset$.

Let $s = inf (\mu (U))_{U \in W}$ , by the defintion of $inf$ there is a sequence $\{U_n\} \subset W$ s.t $\mu(U_n) \to s$ .

Define $U = \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} U_n$, then by direct calculation we get $\mu(U) = s$.

Now I want to show that $U$ is the right set (given $\epsilon)$, but im not sure how.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countable intersection of open sets need not be open. Also, you need to somehow prove that $s=\mu(E)$.

Here is something that works: For each $\delta>0$, let $$E_\delta=\{x\in X\mid d(x,y)<\delta\text{ for some }y\in E\}.$$
Then $m<n$ implies $E_{1/n}\subseteq E_{1/m}$ and $E=\bigcap_n E_{1/n}$, which implies $\mu(E)=\lim_n \mu(E_{1/n})$ which implies $\mu(E_{1/n})-\mu(E)<\epsilon$ for some $n$. Fill in the details.

Comment: What is the open set $U$ ?

Comment: also , $E_{1/n} \subset E $ so $\mu(E_{1/n})  - \mu(E) \le 0 $ so it will be trivial that it is less then $\epsilon$

Comment: For all $x\in E$, $d(x,y)<\delta$ for some $y\in E$; just take $y=x$. Therefore $E\subseteq E_\delta$. Each $E_\delta$ is open.

Comment: $E  = \cap E_{1/n}$ so  i get that $E \subset E_{\delta}$ . im not sure about the rest of your argument. can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: All you have to show is: Each $E_\delta$ is open. If $\langle A_n\rangle$ is a decreasing sequence of measurable sets in a finite measure space, then $\mu(\bigcap A_n)=\lim_n\mu(A_n)$, and, following that, that one of the $E_{1/n}$ can serve as the desired open set.

Comment: Alright, i got most of it, one last thing - why does $E_{\delta}$ is open? i can express it as follows: $E_{\delta }= (\cup_{x \in X} B(x,\delta) ) \cap E$

Comment: I think I got it - $E_{\delta} = \cup_{y \in Y }B(y,\delta)$ , right?

Comment: You have to take the union over $E$, not $Y$: $E_\delta=\bigcup_{y\in E} B(y,\delta)$

Comment: yea, i wrote it just after that, thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68074/discussion-between-liad-and-michael-greinecker).